# In LUIS, can the children of an Entity be required via the parent?

Tags: action, children, azure-language-understanding

Heya folks so I'm working on a LUIS bot and I've run into a bit of confusion regarding how entities work.

So I have this LUIS app set up with a single Entity and a single Intent. This Entity, called Alert, has three children, each of which is an Alert Type. The Intent, called AddAlert, has one Action Parameter: AlertType. This Parameter is supposed to be required, so I checked that box. The Parameter's type is Alert (the parent Entity), and its Prompt is, "What kind of alert?"

So a chat with this app should go like this:

"Add an [insert Alert type here] alert."

Or...

"Add an alert."

Whereupon the Prompt should be triggered.

The problem I'm having, though, is that the Prompt is always triggered. So LUIS is obviously recognising the keywords for the Intent, but it's not making the association for the Entity types necessary to fulfill the required Parameter. When training LUIS, I assigned the children Entity types to the words associated with them, and I figured that using the parent as the required Entity would allow any child to fulfill the requirement. Is that not the case? I tried finding more information on this matter but came up short. I suppose I could make the Parameter not required, but that would complicate things quite a bit. Moreover, I need to be able to differentiate between the three Alert types. Is there something I'm missing? Can I require any single child of an Entity and not every single child?

For reference, here's the Intent's info: [image: AddAction Intent]

Any help or information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All righty so this is pretty funny. LUIS has been completely revamped such that all that action business doesn't exist any more. Thus, this question is now kind of irrelevant. Yay?